# combining two lambda expression query

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the follwing two lambda expression. Can you please help me how can I combine them into one.

```
private bool CheckForNonUniqueRollNumbers(IEnumerable<EmployeeInfoDto> empDtos)
{

    var dtosToCheck = empDtos.Where(dto => dto.ExceptionIfAny == null).ToList();
    var allNumbersEmpty = empDtos.All(dto => dto.Identity.RollNumber == "");
    if (dtosToCheck.Any() && !allSerialNumbersEmpty)
    {

    }
```

I want to combine above two queries

I tried the following query, but I am not sure if this is correct

```
var dtosToCheck = empDtos.Where(dto => dto.ExceptionIfAny == null 
    || dto.Identity.RollNumber == "").ToList();
    if (dtosToCheck.Any())
     {

     }
```

Thanks.

Comment: is your main target to satisfy either of the condition or both of them?

Comment: Why do you want to combine them? Your queries are more readable, as it's currently written. IMO!

Comment: I think the written combined query is right one.

Comment: @vikscool: Yes. both the conditions should satisfy                                      -S.Akbar: if I combine, then I can just have one variable sayinf "isDtoValid"

Comment: @SurajRai if both are required then the query that you have written is correct, only if you don't want two separate query results.

Answer (score 1):

If both conditions should be satisfied (together at same time), You should use `&&` to logically connect them (logical <kbd>AND</kbd>):

```
var allNumbersEmpty = empDtos
                            .Where(dto => dto.ExceptionIfAny == null
                                   && dto.Identity.RollNumber == "")
                            .ToList();
```

---

Your query with `||` will make a logical <kbd>OR</kbd>, which will apply if one or the other condition applies.